# How to set vertex radius when using skin modifier?

Tags: python, add-on, vertices, select

I have this method that I want to use to change the skin size of the skin modifier.

If I do this, everything works fine:

```
def make_uniform_width() -> None:
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
    bpy.ops.transform.skin_resize(
        value=( self.properties.skin_size, self.properties.skin_size, self.properties.skin_size ),
    )
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
```

I can just use: `bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')` to change the value on all vertecies simultaniously.

But I want to select specific vertecies to do the skin_resize. So I thought this could work. But I have no access to the vertecies it seems.

```
def make_increase_width(self):
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
    size = self.properties.skin_size
    for iteration in self._iterations:
        for vert in bpy.ops.object.vertecies:
            if vert.index in self._iterations[iteration]:
                vert.select = True
            else:
                vert.select = False

        size += self.properties.width_increase
        bpy.ops.transform.skin_resize(value=( size, size, size ))
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
```

Is there a way to select specific vertecies from editmode?

EDIT:
I tried this, but it's too slow te execute. Maybe I will have to look for another way to change the skin width.

```
def make_increase_width(self, vein_cluster_object):
    for iteration in self._iterations:
        vein_cluster_object.vertex_groups.new(name='growth-iteration-%i' % iteration)
    for iteration,group in zip(self._iterations,vein_cluster_object.vertex_groups):
        group.add(self._iterations[iteration], weight=1, type='REPLACE')
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
    size = self.properties.skin_size
    for iteration in self._iterations:
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
        bpy.ops.object.vertex_group_deselect()
        bpy.ops.object.vertex_group_set_active(group='growth-iteration-%i' % iteration)
        bpy.ops.object.vertex_group_select()
        bpy.ops.transform.skin_resize(value=( size, size, size ))
        size += self.properties.width_increase
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
```

I found it, I think. This should theoretically do the trick:

```
def make_increase_width(self):
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
    size = self.properties.skin_size
    active_object = bpy.context.active_object
    for iteration in self._iterations:
        for vert in active_object.data.vertices:
            if vert.index in self._iterations[iteration]:
                vert.select = True
            else:
                vert.select = False
        bpy.ops.transform.skin_resize(value=( size, size, size ))
        size += self.properties.width_increase
        print(iteration, size)
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
```

But it's very slow to execute. It seems having this line in the loop `bpy.ops.transform.skin_resize(value=( size, size, size ))` makes it too hard to do. It will select a maximum of 20 verts for about 60 iterations but somehow it will take far to long for it to run. I'm not sure how come.

Comment: Ah, `bpy.ops.object.vertex_group_select()` I will have to make vertex_groups I suspect

Comment: Is it just a spelling problem? "vertecies" is "vertices"

Comment: That was very hopeful but no. `or vert in bpy.ops.object.vertices:
TypeError: 'BPyOpsSubModOp' object is not iterable`

Comment: vertices is an object property from context.object.data (not bpy.ops), depending on what the overall context is in your code.

Comment: Yes, I think I have found out that: `active_object = bpy.context.active_object` is giving me access to the vertecies. But `vert.select = True` is not actually selecting anything it seems. Hmm. ( I updated my question with the full code )

Comment: Should select vertices in object mode.

Comment: But this method is: `bpy.ops.transform.skin_resize(value=( size, size, size ))` only working in edit mode if I understand correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98805/discussion-between-lemon-and-dion-snoeijen).

Comment: Or should I select the verts in object mode. Then switch to edit mode Do the skin resize and switch back to do it again? Let me try :)

Answer (score 2):

@lemon Was kind enough to help me find this answer:

```
def make_increase_width(self):
    size = self.properties.skin_size
    obj = bpy.context.active_object
    for iteration in self._iterations:
        size += self.properties.width_increase
    for iteration in self._iterations:
        for vert_index in self._iterations[iteration]:
            obj.data.skin_vertices[''].data[vert_index].radius = (size, size)
        size -= self.properties.width_increase
```

This is outside of edit mode, very fast and exactly what I needed.